# Significance of asymptotes in root locus

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

What is the significance of asymptotes in the root locus of a linear time invariant system. Does it say that for that particular pole on which it is starting doesn't have a practical pole in the closed loop if the open loop gain is taken to infinity?

Answer (score 2):

The poles of your root locus plot will move in the direction of those asymptotes when you increase your open-loop gain.

The asymptotes can (e.g.) help you understand if increasing (or decreasing) your gain will move your poles towards the stable (negative half for a continuous system) or unstable region in your root-locus plot.

P.S. Some software (like Matlab) will show you the gain needed for placing a particular location on the asymptote (which will also move the other poles!) see [here](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/design-a-yaw-damper-for-a-747-jet-transport.html#f0-1000201) under "Root Locus Design"

Answer (score 0):

The aymptotes show the tendency of the pole movements in open loop.